# Is there a better MySql Query

Tags: mysql, sql

Can someone suggest a better way to write this query? The goal is to get all active members, except members with member type of EXH or AUX, no Canada members or members with NULL in the country.

I have tried many examples from this site but still getting too many results.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `members`
WHERE
    `STATUS` = 'A' AND `MEMBER_TYPE` <> 'EXH' AND `MEMBER_TYPE` <> 'AUX' AND 
    `COUNTRY` <> 'Canada' AND `COUNTRY` IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: You mentioned you are getting too many results... are the results correct though? Based on your description, your query does exactly that.

Comment: you can add a few improvements -  to limit the results for example if you only want 10 results, do Select TOP 10 *,  you can also add with(nolock) to your table to prevent locking rows.  to return less results though, you will need more criteria for the where

Comment: as an aside, you should list the columns you want to select, rather than *. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/what-is-the-reason-not-to-use-select

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Are you getting results with member type EXH or AUX, or Canada members or members with nulls in the country?

Comment: I changed the code to :SELECT
    ID, PREFIX, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, FULL_ADDRESS, EMAIL
FROM
    `members_name`
WHERE
    `STATUS` = 'A' AND `MEMBER_TYPE` <> 'EXH' AND `MEMBER_TYPE` <> 'AUX' AND `COUNTRY` <> 'Canada' AND 

`COUNTRY` IS NOT NULL

Comment: @JoshAdams, you are giving Microsoft SQL Server proprietary syntax, not supported by MySQL.

Comment: @BillKarwin thanks for the catch, out of habit. Should use Limit for mysql.

Answer (score 0):

By default, a SQL query will return *all* records that match.

If you want to return a smaller set of records, you need to explicitly state that.  The methods for doing so vary from one DB to another; for MySQL, you'll need to add LIMIT [n], where [n] is the number of results you want.

You should be a bit careful doing this, though.  If you are going to want the rest of them - like, maybe you want "the first 100 results, but then later you want the *next* 100", you'll need to track an *offset* in addition.  This can introduce other complexities depending on the ordering of the records... but from your question, it sounds like such concerns may be outside the scope of your present issue.  (If not, feel free to edit your question with more detail about your use case.)

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Answer (score 0):

i think this does the work too with slight short handing`SELECT * FROM`members`WHERE`STATUS`= 'A' AND`MEMBER_TYPE`not in ('EXH','AUX') AND`COUNTRY`IS NOT NULL AND`COUNTRY`<> 'Canada'`